# Bit operations in javascript

Tags: javascript

In javascript, number are all of type double, so is it faster to use bit operations than to add, subtract, multiply, and divide? Such as division and shift.

I tried division and shift operations and found that they were about the same speed.
I want to know how the js interpreter implements bit operations.
Thanks!

Comment: wondering is nice. Do you have an actual question?

Comment: I think that really depends on how the environment handles it (Node.js, JSC, V8 etc. may have different approaches).

Comment: The real question is: does it matter if one is slightly faster than the other? If you have performance issues with your code I doubt that the bottleneck is either division or right shift. It's more likely that you make sequential IO requests instead of making them concurrent. Or you have an 1+N problem on you hands. Or you use a non-optimal algorithm that has O(n²) instead of O(n).

Comment: [Which is faster?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I just want to know how js implements the shift operation of type number. It is true that maybe different engines handle it differently. I was actually implementing the RSA algorithm for the purpose of learning, so I implemented the large integer class and Montgomery Reduction myself. And that involves shifting operations. I didn't choose c++ because I really like js as a programming language

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to know how the js interpreter implements bit operations.

Because Javascript [has a specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/) and it is extensive and defines pretty much all the basic operations of the language, that's an easy query to get the answer to: just look for bitwise operations, like [bitwise shift operators](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-bitwise-shift-operators). This delegates to the abstract operation [`EvaluateStringOrNumericBinaryExpression`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-evaluatestringornumericbinaryexpression), which delegates to [`ApplyStringOrNumericBinaryOperator`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-applystringornumericbinaryoperator), which goes through an *operations table* based on the type of the left operand and the operator, let's say `Number` and `>>` for a right shift since you're talking about division.

This operation is delegated to [`Number::signedRightShift`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-numeric-types-number-signedRightShift) which is defined as:

> 1. Let `lnum` be ! `ToInt32(x)`.
> 2. Let `rnum` be ! `ToUint32(y)`.
> 3. Let `shiftCount` be `ℝ(rnum)` modulo 32.

And there you have it, bitwise ops work on the int32 representation of the number.

> In javascript, number are all of type double, so is it faster to use bit operations than to add, subtract, multiply, and divide? Such as division and shift.

That depends on the runtime. When performing sequences of bitwise operations, odds are good modern JIT will just keep the number as an int32 and not bother converting back to a double (in fact `n|0` is how [asmjs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asm.js) specified typing a variable as an int32). However a jit might also compile a multiplication or division by a multiple of 2 to a shift so... these really are not questions which can be answered in the general case, they're going to depend on runtime decisions which might not even be local. The only thing you can do is profile and benchmark your actual software.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Your answer is very helpful.